# How can I get clicks to be ignored by my tab onClick code when clicking inside the ContentPane

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout, dojo.gridx

I have the following `dojo` javascript code for picking up the click of a tab and child tabs of my `TabContainer/ContentPanes` and getting their tab ids. This is the only code that has worked for child tabs, all other tab selection code only worked for the parent tabs only.

```
// Pickup the onClick and get the ID of the tab or sub tab being clicked, this is used in the case switch statement for updating the grid accordingly
    var tabContainerPanel = registry.byId('myDivID');   //get dijit from its source dom element

    on(tabContainerPanel, "Click", function (event) {
        selectedTabString = tabContainerPanel.selectedChildWidget.title;

        if (typeof tabContainerPanel.selectedChildWidget.selectedChildWidget !== 'undefined'){
            // There are no child tabs, parent tab only
            selectedTabString = tabContainerPanel.selectedChildWidget.selectedChildWidget.title;
        }
        // Update tab you selected when you select it! setGridData will update it every 10 seconds after it is selected.
        switch (selectedTabString) {
            case "blah1":
                Some code blah blah;
                break;
            case "blah2":
                Some code blah blah;
                break;
And so on...another 13 cases...
```

My problem is when I click inside my `dojo` `gridx` object which resides within a `ContentPane` that resides inside my `TabContainer`, the `onClick` is being captured and causing other code to be executed specified only for tab onClicks and it is preventing my mouse clicks from working correctly for the `dojo` components in the cells of the `gridx` like for buttons and editable text areas etc.

How do I get the tab `onClick` code to only work on the tabs themselves and not the child objects?

Here is how I am adding the `gridx` to the `TabContainer`:

```
    // Every tab is a TabContaner, including sub tabs. Tabs and sub tabs contain ContentPane objects
    var tcmain = new TabContainer({doLayout: false}, 'myDivID');

    var tab1 = new ContentPane({title: "Tab1", content: gridx1});

    var tab2 = new TabContainer({title: "Tab2", doLayout: false, nested: true});
    var tab2Child1 = new ContentPane({title: "Tab2child1", content: gridx2});
    var tab2Child2 = new ContentPane({title: "Tab2Child2", content: gridx3});

    // tab2
    tab2.addChild(tab2Child1);
    tab2.addChild(tab2Child2);

    // Add Parent tabs to main TabContainer, tcmain. Parent Tabs contain their child tab objects
    tcmain.addChild(tab1);
    tcmain.addChild(tab2);


<Code example ABOVE is incerted here>


    tcmain.startup();
```

Comment: can you show how  you have added `gridx` code to the tab container and how are you handling click events within the gridx component? what I can suggest is that you need use the `event.preventDefault()` **within** the `gridx` **onclick** function handler so that the `click` event does not bubble up to the parent of tab container.

Comment: @frank thanks - added what you requested, a very shorted version with modified tab gridx names. Note that the first code example is inserted above the tcmain.startup(); line near the bottom. The click behavior has not been modified by me for the gridx, and I don't fully understand how it works, so in my project, it should be behaving like the default behavor.

Comment: I am not familiar with gridx. can you try adding the `onClick` property to the ContentPane i.e `new ContentPane({title: "Tab2child1", content: gridx2, onClick:function(e){e.preventDefault;e.stopPropagation;}});`. Hope it works.

Comment: @frank Thanks for the suggestion - I tried it and it didn't work. I wrote it exactly as you have it above. I did figure out a hack to solve the issue temporarily by using an if statement, checking the last selected tab and comparing it to the current one and if it is the same as the last selected tab to bypass the switch statement.

Comment: does the `onClick` that was added above to the ContentPane get **fired**? you can check by adding a console.log statement in the onClick function handler. I hope you have added the onClick function handler to **All** the content panes.

Comment: @frank I added the console.log and it does get logged, showing that it is firing. I did add it to all the content panes yes. Here is the line:     var tab1 = new ContentPane({title: "Tab1", content: tab1Gridx, onClick:function(e){console.log("onClick Fired!");e.preventDefault;e.stopPropagation;}});